# How to end tLoop when desired criteria reached

Tags: java, talend

Here is my process:

[image: Job Layout and tJava_1 configuration]

You can see the Java code in tJava_1. It parses out the data from the file and if it reached the last search page it will set a value to true. This is meant to be the stop criteria for the tLoop_1, as shown here:

[image: tLoop configuration]

Am I handling the Talend variables wrong? How can I stop the loop from running once I reached the criteria in my Java code?

Comment: context.lastpage == false -> until it is false the code will run :) Alternatively you can do a For loop with the same settings (+ the == false)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need the "Declaration" or the "Iteration" values. What you want is a variable in the "Condition" that is a boolean that evaluates to `true` and is set to `false` when you are wanting to end the loop.

Best practice says you should use context variables for actual contexts supplied to a job either on run time or when starting a child job and then use the globalMap for globally available variables across a single job.

So in this case you should initialise a boolean globalMap variable set to true (you could do this in a tJava component with `globalMap.put("loop",true)` or use the tSetGlobalVar component) and then in your tJavaRow you can set the globalMap variable to false with `globalMap.put("loop",false)`.

If you were to use "loop" as your globalMap variable then you'd use `((Boolean)globalMap.get("loop"))` in your "Condition" in the tLoop.

A worked simple example of this might look like the following:

[image: While loop job layout]

First we set the loop variable to `true` as we want it to at least start!

[image: tSetGlobalVar configuration]

And then we set the condition of the while loop to the boolean global variable:

[image: tLoop configuration]

And then finally we run some code in the tJava component that does something and conditionally sets the global variable to false, ending the loop:

```
if (((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_2_CURRENT_ITERATION")) == 3) {
    globalMap.put("loop", false);
} else {
    System.out.println(((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_2_CURRENT_ITERATION")));
};
```

Comment: That solved my question. ydaetskcoR you helped me out now around 3 times already. Let me bow in honor. =)